# VSCode tasks.json: Environment variables not resolving correctly

Tags: visual-studio-code, environment-variables

I'm encountering an issue with setting up environment variables in my tasks.json file in the VSCode. Despite attempting various configurations, I haven't been able to get it to work as expected. Here's the relevant section of my tasks.json file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/build",
        "env": {
            "ESPPORT": "/dev/ttyUSB1",
            "ESPBAUD": "1200",
            "IDF_PYTHON_ENV_PATH": "${env:HOME}/.espressif/python_env/idf5.1_py3.10_env",
            "IDF_PATH": "${env:HOME}/esp/esp-idf-v5.1.2",
            "GCC_PATH": "${env:HOME}/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32s3-elf/esp-12.2.0_20230208/xtensa-esp32s3-elf/bin",
            "PYTHON_PATH": "${env:HOME}/.espressif/python_env/idf5.1_py3.10_env/bin",
            "PATH": "${env:PATH}:${env:GCC_PATH}:${env:PYTHON_PATH}"
        }
    },
    "tasks": [
        // tasks configurations
    ]
}
```

Despite setting up the environment variables in this manner, it seems that they are not being resolved correctly when running tasks within VSCode. I've tried different variations, including using an external shell script to set the environment, but nothing seems to work.

Can someone provide insight into what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you're missing the part of a [mre] where you tell us what you're actually observing. also, this isn't even a repro. there's no actual task definition to demonstrate what you're observing.